# Centering a UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, uibezierpath

I have a UIBezierPath thats a rounded square. It somewhat looks like this: [image]

Here's my code for the shape:

```
let shape = SKShapeNode()
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x:(0), y: (0), width: (250), height: (400)), cornerRadius: 64).cgPath
    shape.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    print(shape.position)
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.white
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.white
    shape.lineWidth = 5
    addChild(shape)
```

I want to center it in the middle of the screen, but using

```
shape.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height)
```

doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you center the UIBezierPath within the shape node. For example,

```
let width:CGFloat = 250
let height:CGFloat = 400
shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x:-width/2, y: -height/2, width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: 64).cgPath
```

You can center the shape in the scene by setting its position to (0, 0).